# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz,

Tags: java, audio, processing

I get the following exception when my program tries to open the microphone when i try running the program on both MacOS X and Windows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.getLine(DirectAudioDevice.java:174)
    at guitar.tab.generator.main.MainFrame.setNewSoundListener
```

This used to work before and suddenly it does not seem to work for me, wondering if this is because of an issue in the JRE I'm using.

```
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, true);

    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

    TargetDataLine line;
    line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    final int numberOfSamples = bufferSize;
    line.open(format, numberOfSamples);
    line.start();

    AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(line);
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(stream);
    reader = new AudioReader(audioStream, bufferSize, overlap);
    reader.addAudioProcessor(new PitchEvaluator(sampleRate, bufferSize, this));
```

Comment: @dav191 can you post most info for context ? (what is the value of `sampleRate`, what variable type is `mixer`, etc.). Also, is this raw Java or are you panning to use [Processing](https://processing.org) and an audio library (e.g. Minim/Beads/etc.) ?

Comment: What JRE were you using before and which one are you using now? AFAIK, the new JREs should support this code as it is considered part of the core libraries. The only thing slightly unusual to me is the BigEndian in your format. I've seen this instead of LittleEndian before, but kind of rarely. Maybe check on the availability of this as a line? Have you seen this tutorial on accessing resources, checking lines? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html